# Expected end of line error on applescript trying to fill a webform

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript, jira

I'm trying to come up with an apple script I can run in order to fill out some web forms I do every day (JIRA ticket forms).

I've created this JS script which is working when I run it on Chrome's console:

```
document.getElementById('summary').value="Inserted text"
```

So now I create my applescript in order to be able to externally execute it but I always get *"Syntax Error . Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token*."

This is the code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

execute javascript document.getElementById('summary').value="Inserted text" in document 1   

end tell
```

I know *tell application* works, but I don't understand how to solve the Syntax Error and make the applescript work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in document 1` syntax is for Safari.

With Google Chrome you should to talk to the `active tab` of the target `window`, e.g.:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1
        execute javascript "document.getElementById('summary').value = 'Inserted text';"
    end tell
end tell
```

Or substitute the *window number* with its `name`.

Comment: While you’re version of the code will function correctly most of the time, there are times where window 1 will not be the active window… where the active window was actually intended to be the target.  I explained in detail, a scenario in which your version will throw an error because it's sending a JavaScript command to the wrong window

Comment: @wch1zpink, First of all, my answer points out that the `in document 1` syntax is for Safari, which was the primary reason the code in the OP was failing. Secondly, I stated "With Google Chrome you should to talk to the active tab of the target window, e.g.:", note the `e.g.:` at the end of that quoted line! It's example code, not necessarily meant to be the absolute way the user uses it and why I also stated "Or substitute the _window number_ with its `name`. The onus is on the user to formulate the _code_ to meet their needs not necessarily use verbatim an example that shows how it can work!

Comment: My comments and responses are only because I do not believe your comment “That's just two different ways to say the same thing that I've already said!” to be true.  My solution to the OP’s question is a perfectly valid alternative.  However, your statement outside of your code.. “Or substitute the window number with its name.” will address the same issue that my solution was intended.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementById('summary').value = 'Inserted text';"
end tell
```

---

**OR** - Compacted down to one line of code only

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementById('summary').value = 'Inserted text';"
```

---

The reason I chose this code is because of this following example..

In Google Chrome I started out with one window, then one window with 4 tabs.  Next,
Split up those tabs into 4 separate windows. After this, I selected the bottom right window to make that the “active window”.  Thinking that, that bottom right window, being active, would now be “window 1”…  I would be wrong (according to the results of this following script)

[image]

If I ran the script in “window 1” it would have run on the upper left window in the browser, which was window 1 when I only had one window with one tab. It retained its initial value.  The problem is that is not the window I wanted to run my script on

[image]

So apparently window 1 is not necessarily the front window

Comment: That's just two different ways to say the same thing that I've already said!

Comment: @user3439894  I have to respectfully disagree..  Your version of the code targets window 1, Which may or may not be the front active window.  My version targets the front active window whether it is window 1 or not.